# How to f.write .append results to CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, csv

I edited some Python code to use the .append method, which means that the way I had written my `f.write()` will no longer work (`TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list`).

This is part of a scraper, which I've tested and can print. Prior to editing my loop to include .append, I was exporting to .csv with the following line of code:

```py
f.write(product_name + "," + product_number + "," + category + "\n")
```

That will no longer work, and I'm not sure how to edit it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've edited my loop to look like this:

```
containers = page_soup.findAll("tr",{"class":"products"})

product_name = []
product_number = []
category = []

for container in containers:
    product_name.append( container.a.text )
    product_number.append( container.div.text )
    category.append( container.select_one('td:nth-of-type(4)').text.strip() )
```

I believe I understand that the addition of the .append method means I can't use the f.write approach shown above (list vs. string, right?). When I do use the `f.write` code shown above, I get a "`TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list`", which I think I understand.

I know my loop is working because this code kicks out the proper results:

```py
print("product_name:", product_name)
print("product_number:", product_number)
print("category: ", category)
```

How do I now write this to .csv?

Comment: I would recommend using the pandas library

Comment: you can use `CSVDictAdapter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid iterating over the items twice, you could simply write to the file within the `for` loop:

```
product_names = []
product_numbers = []
categories = []

with open('file.csv','w') as f:
    for container in containers:
            product_name = container.a.text
            product_number = container.div.text
            category =  container.select_one('td:nth-of-type(4)').text.strip() 

            product_names.append(product_name)
            product_numbers.append(product_number)
            categories.append(category)

            f.write(product_name + "," + product_number + "," + category + "\n")
```

You might also want to use the `csv` module for writing rows to the file instead of manually using string concatenation to create rows:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv','w') as f:
    csv_out = csv.writer(f)
    for container in containers:
            #...same as above...

            csv_out.writerow([product_name, product_number, category])
```

Comment: Won't that still give me "TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list" even if it's within the ```for``` loop?

Comment: No, because `product_name`, `product_number` and `category` are strings here. I've pluralized the list names for clarity.

Comment: Thanks. I'm working with it but am getting "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'"

Comment: Check the variable names. I changed the list names to `product_names`, `product_numbers` and `categories`. So it should be `product_names.append()` not `product_name.append()`

Comment: But then won't I get "name 'company_names' is not defined". Sorry...noob here.

Comment: Yes you'll need to rename them in the definition eg. `product_names = []` (instead of `product_name = []`). Added that to my code.

Answer (score 1):

Same way as before, just do it after establishing the complete contents of `product_name`, `product_number`, and `category`, and do it one row at a time:

```
items = zip(product_name, product_number, category)  # zip these three lists into a single 2D list
with open("my_file.csv", 'w') as f:
    for item in items:
        f.write(f"{item[0]},{item[1]},{item[2]}\n")
```

You might also look into using the `csv` library if you're getting into anything more complicated than this.